# Export a CSV from Heroku Redis DB to an AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, redis

I have inherited an app in Heroku which has a Redis database. The app is writing csvs to Redis db.

I can access the Redis db in terminal using:

```
heroku redis:cli -a myapp -c myapp
```

I found this on heroku's documentation. After that I can use the `GET "key"` to get my file. But all that does is, it prints the entire file's contents in the terminal.

How can I save the file to a csv?
How can I then export it to my aws s3 bucket?

I am new to Redis and Heroku.

Any help/guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you paste the command which GET "key" as per your requriement

Comment: I am not sure I understand. The key is set in the app when the file is getting saved to Redis. For example, I have some data processed and the end output is saved to Redis with a key called "data_output.csv". When I use the GET command, I use it like this: `GET "data_output.csv"`

Comment: > command is used to save the output of the command in a file, so my recommendation is run the command with > which will save file temporarily and upload it to S3 or wherever you want. I haven't tried with redis like this.